# Getting Outlook .msg file contents with Objective-C

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ipad, outlook

I am writing an app for the iPhone and iPad and I need it to show a preview of an Outlook .msg file.  Quick Look, unsurprisingly, doesn't support this file type and therefore I need some way of parsing the contents.

Is there any way of getting the contents of an **Outlook .msg** file with Objective-C?  I want to be able to view the contents as HTML (even if I have to manipulate the contents a bit afterwards)  I've seen references made to using OLE streams and possibly XML parsing in Windows but not sure how these apply in Objective-C.  There are .msg reader apps out there for iOS, so I know it's possible but struggling to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outlook .msg files are stored as *OLE compound documents* (aka *COM stuctured storage*). So you mainly need a library to read this format. A quick search turned up [POLE](http://pole.berlios.de/) and [libgsf](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/libgsf/). They are written in C++ and C, respectively, but that's supported on the iPhone as well.

Then there's some [file format information](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/) that shows how the compound document format is used to store the different parts of an email.

Comment: Did you managed to run POLE on iOS? Do you have some pointers or reference material which can help me out as I am struggling a lot with that. Some sample code will be immensely helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSG file format is documented by Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396