# Reading Microsoft Outlook MSG Content in pure C code

Tags: c, file, outlook, msg

I need to read some Microsoft Outlook MSG file in pure C code. What I need is a library that doesn't depend on any particular framework (.NET, Java, etc), so a library/class/set of functions completely written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're okay with MFC or ATL (which would be C++), you should take a look at [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/files/article.php/c13487/How-to-Read-a-MS-Outlook-msg-File-Using-ATL-and-MFC.htm#page-1) article. Also, the format is described in detail [here](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/).

What you'll essentially be doing is reading the nodes which have information in ASCII text format, which boils down to the `__substg1.0_xxxxxxxx` nodes ending with 001E.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but what I'm looking for is something that doesn't depend on MFC and ATL, so I need a pure C library with no references to any system library function such as StgOpenStorage and so on. Anyway I think I have found something useful on another post here: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886727/getting-outlook-msg-file-contents-with-objective-c?rq=1[/link] where a user suggests to use a library called POLE to read the structure, so I think I'll try to start using this.