# How to open ".msg" (Microsoft Outlook Message) file in Objective-C or in C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, msg

I am currently developing a business logic for **iDevices**, where I need to open and display **.msg** (Microsoft Outlook Message) file. I have already found some answers in internet, but I am expecting concrete answer rather abstract.

> Either a way to open directly with **Objective-C** or at least with the
>   help of any **C/C++** third party library.

Have anyone any idea...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found the spec of the `.msg` file format?

Comment: I have found something https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F5%2FD%2FD%2F5DD33FDF-91F5-496D-9884-0A0B0EE698BB%2F%5BMS-OXMSG%5D.pdf&ei=eJy7U_OfLq3X7AaOv4HwCQ&usg=AFQjCNHcAPp4CLQh-INfOosxJVj32o25vQ&sig2=Mo-ftdILiF7fkrQ6IsR6RA&bvm=bv.70138588,d.bGE

Comment: That looks like a good document and should be more than enough to read a `.msg` file.

Comment: THis doc is Microsoft's definition of its own format, so it's the definitive reference.  However, don't underestimate complexity: it's build on top of a binary compound object format (defined in another reference) + handling of attachments and several coexisting data format versions.  If it can help, here a portable C++ library for reading at least the underlying data format:  http://www.dimin.net/software/pole/

Comment: Thank you I need time to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try POLE ([this is the right link](http://www.dimin.net/software/pole/)) and [LibGSF](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libgsf).

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886727/getting-outlook-msg-file-contents-with-objective-c).

AFAIK, MSG files use OLE2 file format.

Cheers.

Comment: I tried a bit but I could not come forward because I am lacking of C/C++ knowledge. But give me some time to try again. I would be happy if you give me a concrete answer with some example.

Comment: @Goppinath
were you able to view .msg file ultimately by any method ?

Comment: @ZaEeMZaFaR No it is still open :-(

Comment: Hi, anyone got solution?